# Are there any limit on number of files uploaded to parse application?

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on an ios project that requires users to upload photos to the server for limited time (like 1-2 weeks at most and then files will be deleted).

I am expecting that each user will be uploading about 50-200 files each. So there will be lots of file upload operations going on with in my application.

I've read that there used to be a "500 file" limit on parse.com services, so i decided to use amazon s3 for file storage few months ago.

(heres the archive question and answer link)
[Is there a limit on the number of files I can store in Parse?](https://parse.com/questions/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-files-i-can-store-in-parse)

The project delayed for few months, and now when i check the parse website, i see that there is a 20gb storage for free and no mention about number of files limit.

So should i use parse for file storage or shall i continiue use amazon s3?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is No upper limit to the number of files you can upload to Parse that I have found, provided you are willing to pay for it.

We have an installation with many files (think thousands) and have not run into any difficulty.

Your only concern would be price. I'm not sure how Parse calculates total storage space for their pricing. If it's moment to moment, you will be in much better shape than if files count until the end of the month. Make sure you really delete files when done with them and regularly run the file cleanup on the Parse app settings page to remove orphan files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i don't think that i will exceed the 20gb limit. files will mostly be jpg files, i hope i'll come to a point that i will start to concern about cost of exceeding gb's ;)